# Finding a real structure $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ of a complex vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

**Definition:**
Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of $dim_{\mathbb{C}}(V)=n$. Then $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ is said to be a real structure of $V$ iff

1. $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space
2. $dim_{\mathbb{R}}(V_{\mathbb{R}})=n$
3. there exists an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces $V \simeq V_{\mathbb{R}} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$

**My problem:**
First I try to give a short outline of my rather specific situation, but I try to keep it short. I now consider a representation $\gamma: \pi_1 \to GL(V)$ together with its image $M:=im(\gamma)$ and wanted to show that under certain circumstances, there exists a real structure defined as above and so that $\gamma$ factors over $GL(V_{\mathbb{R}})$. So we have that $\gamma: \pi_1 \hookrightarrow GL(V_{\mathbb{R}})$. Now comes my actual question:

For the case $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ I actually found a way to show that $M \subset GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. But now I’m unsure how I can use this result, to show and express that there exists a real structure for an ordinary $\mathbb{C}$-vectorspace as in the notations above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $V=\Bbb C^n$ and $M\subset \mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$, then $V_\Bbb R:=\Bbb R^n \subset \Bbb C^n$ defines a real structure. Does this answer your question?

In fact, for a group $G$ acting on a complex vector space $V$ of dimension $n$, there exists a real structure for this representation if and only if there is a basis of $V$ such that the isomorphisms induced by the basis $V \cong \Bbb C^n$, $\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb C)\cong \mathrm{GL}(V)$ satisfy that the image of $G$ under this isomorphism lands in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$. In that case one can always take the image of $\Bbb R^n$ under the isomorphism $\Bbb C^n \to V$ as a real structure if that condition is satisfied for the basis in question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.